# python GTK webview not reloading HTML file

Tags: python, webview, gtk, pygtk

using python Im trying to open my HTML file.
parallel Im loading data to my HTML but it is not reflecting in GTK webkit.
but  GTK web view is not loading the runtime data but.

we have option to load data

**map_webview.is_controlled_by_automation()**

but is is not refreshing the page.  any alternate option to refresh the webkit with new data.

*below is my Code*

```
    self.map_window = self.builder.get_object("map_window")
    self.map_webview = self.builder.get_object("webkit")
    # self.map_window.fullscreen()
    #self.map_webview = WebKit2.WebView()
    self.data_file = "file://" + os.getcwd() + "/TrainMap/steptracker.html"
    self.map_webview.load_uri(self.data_file)
    # self.map_window.add(self.map_webview)
    self.map_window.show_all()
    self.map_webview.is_controlled_by_automation()
```

Comment: WebKit won't watch the original file for changes. If you want that, you'll need to implement it yourself using something like [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved
used another approach(Pycario)  to develop the web-view

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).